# Mockito uses method stubbing from other test method in the same class

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a method for the happy path and an Exception scenario.
My class looks like this

```
class MyClass
{
  @Autowired
  AnotherClass anotherClass;

  public Object myMethod() throws MyException
  {
     try{
       //DO SOME STUFF
       anotherClass.anotherMethod();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        throw MyException(e);
     }
  }
}
```

I am testing the above myMethod like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MyClassTest
{
   @Mock
   AnotherClass anotherClass; 
   @InjectMocks
   MyClass myClass;

   @Test
   public void myMethodTest()
   {
      when(anotherClass.anotherMethod()).thenReturn("Mocked data");

      myClass.myMethod();
   }
   
   @Test(expected=MyException.class)
   public void myMethodExpTest()
   {
      when(anotherClass.anotherMethod()).thenThrow(MyException.class);

      myClass.myMethod();
   }
}
```

When I checked the code coverage using Jacoco, it does not coverage the exception catch block. I tried debugging the test in my Eclipse IDE. I am getting the "Mocked Data" for the exception test method. It appears to be the mocking to that method is not getting reset for the second method.
Is there a way to flush the method mocking/stubbing from previous test methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would consider this a bug. But you can manually reset mocks

```
@Before
public void resetMock() {
  Mockito.reset(anotherClass);
}
```